# Complexity of Function Call in c++ inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance

I use C++. Ihave a doubt regarding inheritance and functions.  I have the following classes.

```
         class A 
          { 
               public :
                  void Fun1();
                  void Fun2();
          }

          class B : public A
          {
              public :
                 void Fun3();
                 void Fun4();
          }

          void B::Fun3()
          {
              //some code goes here
              Fun1();
              //again some code
              Fun2();
          }
```

My doubt is how is this           Fun3()      executes ? ie, during compiling will it replace the code for Fun1() and Fun2() or it will keep separate stack for Fun1() and Fun2() ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shall think of it, as if fun1() and fun2() were called with their own local variables ("separate stack"). The compiler may generate such code. But it may also inline the code as long as it can be sure that exacmy the same result and side effects were achieved

Comment: Logically, when you ask a question of the form "x or y", then "x" and "y" should be opposite to each other in some way. `replace the code` and `keep separate stack`... well, how exactly are these two even related to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `Fun1` and `Fun2` are defined in a separate translation unit that's only loaded dynamically at runtime (i.e. a shared library), the C++ compiler ***may*** choose to ***inline*** the code for `Fun1` and `Fun2` into `Fun3()`, which basically means the that code from 1 & 2 is injected into `Fun3()` but may then be optimised based on the surrounding code, so the actual sequence of machine opcodes in `Fun3` may not contain an exact copy of those in `Fun1` or `Fun2`.  Despite being allowed, many compilers only tend to do so only when the definitions of `Fun1` and `Fun2` are in the same translation unit as `Fun3`'s definition, and when there're either no other actual calls to `Fun1` and/or `Fun2`, or the amount of code inside `Fun1` and `Fun2` is relatively small.

Note that inheritance plays no role here: the same would be true if all of Fun1, Fun2 and Fun3 were in the same class, and apart from the `*this` parameter applies to global/namespace functions too.

> keep separate stack for `Fun1()` and `Fun2()`

Whether or not `Fun1` and `Fun2` are inlined, they'll all share the same stack with `Fun3`.  Indeed, all synchronously executed functions in any given thread of a C++ program share the same stack.  Asynchronous signal handlers may have a separate stack.  (There are libraries implementing coroutines for C++ - e.g. in the boost library - but they're not in common use.)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler options, specifically **inline** property:

> By declaring a function inline, you can direct GCC to make calls to
>   that function faster. One way GCC can achieve this is to integrate
>   that function's code into the code for its callers. This makes
>   execution faster by eliminating the function-call overhead; in
>   addition, if any of the actual argument values are constant, their
>   known values may permit simplifications at compile time so that not
>   all of the inline function's code needs to be included. The effect on
>   code size is less predictable; object code may be larger or smaller
>   with function inlining, depending on the particular case. You can also
>   direct GCC to try to integrate all “simple enough” functions into
>   their callers with the option -finline-functions.
>
> GCC implements three different semantics of declaring a function
>   inline. One is available with -std=gnu89 or -fgnu89-inline or when
>   gnu_inline attribute is present on all inline declarations, another
>   when -std=c99, -std=c11, -std=gnu99 or -std=gnu11 (without
>   -fgnu89-inline), and the third is used when compiling C++.

from the [reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Inline.html).